# How to aggregate unknown-typed maps into single map?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{aggregate, col, map, map_concat}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

/**
* A batch application that takes a hard-coded list of strings and counts the words.
*/
object MyBatchApp {
 lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass)
 val jobName = "MyBatchApp"

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   try {
     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(jobName).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
     import spark.implicits._
     val strings = Seq(
       """{"batch_id":"111111111","id":"111111111","lab_data":{"categories":{"alkaloids":null,"cannabinoids":{"compounds":[{"limit":"","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"0.100","max":"","name":"cbd","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"},{"limit":"","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"0.100","max":"","name":"cbg","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0.06374552683896600"}]},"dna":null,"flavonoids":null,"foreign_matter":null,"general":null,"homogeneity":null,"metals":{"compounds":[{"limit":"1000","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"166000","loq":"333.000","max":"","name":"lead","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"24.000"},{"limit":"400.0","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"66000","loq":"133.000","max":"","name":"arsenic","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"32.000"}]},"microbials":{"compounds":[{"limit":"100","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"100","max":"","name":"ecoli","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"},{"limit":"1","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"","max":"","name":"salmonella_spp","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"}]}}}}""",
       """{"batch_id":"222222222","id":"222222222","lab_data":{"categories":{"alkaloids":null,"cannabinoids":{"compounds":[{"limit":"","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"0.100","max":"","name":"cbd","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"},{"limit":"","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"0.100","max":"","name":"cbg","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0.06374552683896600"}]},"dna":null,"flavonoids":null,"foreign_matter":null,"general":null,"homogeneity":null,"metals":{"compounds":[{"limit":"1000","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"166000","loq":"333.000","max":"","name":"lead","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"24.000"},{"limit":"400.0","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"66000","loq":"133.000","max":"","name":"arsenic","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"32.000"}]},"microbials":{"compounds":[{"limit":"100","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"100","max":"","name":"ecoli","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"},{"limit":"1","limitrangehigh":"","limitrangelow":"","lod":"","loq":"","max":"","name":"salmonella_spp","regulatornotes":null,"rpd":"","rsd":"","spike":"","stdev":"","value":"0"}]}}}}"""

     )
     spark.read.json(strings.toDS).createOrReplaceTempView("sample")
     val sourceSchema = spark.sql(s"select lab_data.categories.* from sample").head.schema
     val source = spark.sql(s"select * from sample")
     val parquet = sourceSchema.fields.filter(f =>
       f.dataType.isInstanceOf[StructType] &&
         f.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fieldNames.contains("compounds"))
       .foldLeft(source)((source, f) => source
         .withColumn(s"sample_lab_data_new_categories_${f.name}_compounds",
           aggregate(
             col(s"sample.lab_data.categories.${f.name}.compounds"),
             map(),
//              map().cast("map<string,struct<limit:string,limitrangehigh:string,limitrangelow:string,lod:string,loq:string,max:string,regulatornotes:string,rpd:string,rsd:string,spike:string,stdev:string,value:string>>"),
             (acc, c) => map_concat(acc, map(c.getField("name"), c.dropFields("name")))))
       )
     parquet.show()
   }
 }
}
```

Failed with error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'aggregate(sample.`lab_data`.`categories`.`cannabinoids`.`compounds`, map(), lambdafunction(map_concat(namedlambdavariable(), map(namedlambdavariable().`name`, update_fields(namedlambdavariable()))), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires map<null,null> type, however, 'lambdafunction(map_concat(namedlambdavariable(), map(namedlambdavariable().`name`, update_fields(namedlambdavariable()))), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of map<string,struct<limit:string,limitrangehigh:string,limitrangelow:string,lod:string,loq:string,max:string,regulatornotes:string,rpd:string,rsd:string,spike:string,stdev:string,value:string>> type.; Project [batch_id#5, id#6, lab_data#7, aggregate(lab_data#7.categories.cannabinoids.compounds, map(), lambdafunction(map_concat(cast(lambda x_0#45 as map<string,struct<limit:string,limitrangehigh:string,limitrangelow:string,lod:string,loq:string,max:string,regulatornotes:string,rpd:string,rsd:string,spike:string,stdev:string,value:string>>), map(lambda y_1#46.name, update_fields(lambda y_1#46, DropField(name)))), lambda x_0#45, lambda y_1#46, false), lambdafunction(lambda x_2#47, lambda x_2#47, false)) AS sample_lab_data_new_categories_cannabinoids_compounds#43]
+- Project [batch_id#5, id#6, lab_data#7]    +- SubqueryAlias sample
      +- LogicalRDD [batch_id#5, id#6, lab_data#7], false
```

But when uncomment `map().cast` line it works. I wonder - can it possible to use `map()` without explicit typing? For example in situations when additional fields added.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the schema of the inner structs of `compounds` arrays then use it to cast the initial map value for aggregate function:

```
//...
.foldLeft(source)((source, f) => {
    val arrayOfStructs = col(s"sample.lab_data.categories.${f.name}.compounds")
    val structSchema = source.select(arrayOfStructs(0)).schema.map(_.dataType.simpleString).mkString

    source.withColumn(
      s"sample_lab_data_new_categories_${f.name}_compounds",
      aggregate(
        arrayOfStructs,
        map().cast(s"map<string,$structSchema>"),
        (acc, c) =>
          map_concat(acc, map(c.getField("name"), c.dropFields("name")))
      )
    )
  }
)
//...
```